# Which is better for returning result of some method or instance of a class? and why?

Tags: function

I was just wondered which is better way for returning some result of function or instance of Class?

1)

```
FN() {
    var result = callSomeFN();
    return result;
}

InitClass(int typeId): MyClass {
    MyClass class = new MyClass(typeId);
    return class;
}
```

2)

```
FN() {
    return callSomeFN();
}

InitClass(int typeId): MyClass {
    return new MyClass(typeId);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference I see here is the declaration of a variable. I wouldn't say one is better than the other. If the variable is never going to be used why bother defining it? Just return.

I suppose if you *really* wanted to nitpick it would depend on if you're returning a value or reference type. If it's a reference it doesn't matter since you're going to store something in memory and return a pointer (both the variable and the return value are just pointers to the same memory space). If it's a value type it will end up copying the value and disposing of the version within the function scope. If the variable is never used why create something just to destroy it? The default behavior would be highly language dependent, which you didn't specify.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The language I'm suing, Javascript, PHP, C# mostly. and I was thinking it's better using #2, but I just want to make sure it's okay to use :)